# Order by a whole group

Tags: mysql, sql, rollup

I have a table like this:

```
Brand | Type | Units
Sony | TV | 5
Toshiba | TV | 4
Sony | Radio | 1
Toshiba | Radio | 10
```

and I want it like this:

```
Type | Brand | Units
Radio | Toshiba | 10
Radio | Sony | 1
TV | Sony | 5
TV | Toshiba | 4
```

That is, order it by **Type**, **Brand** based Type's count (10+1 vs 5+4) and then on Units' count (10 vs 1 & 5 vs 4).

What do you think is the best way to achieve that?

I've tried the following which adds a subtotal under each group:

```
select Type, Brand, sum(Units) from mytable
group by Type, Brand, sum(Units) WITH ROLLUP

Type | Brand | sum(Units)
Radio | Toshiba | 10
Radio | Sony | 1
Radio | null | 11
TV | Sony | 5
TV | Toshiba | 4
TV | null | 9
null | null | 20
```

But I see no way to sort by those subtotals.

Comment: Join to a derived table (subquery with alias) to get the subtotals.  Then you can order by them.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to your query as a sub-query and perform the ordering based on the required columns.

```
select type, brand, total
from (
select Type, Brand, sum(Units) as total
from mytable
group by Type, Brand, sum(Units) WITH ROLLUP) t
order by type, total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to order by the total for the type first based on its total.  In MySQL, you can do this with explicit aggregation and a `join`:

```
select tb.*
from (select Type, Brand, sum(Units) as sumunits
      from mytable
      group by Type, Brand
     ) tb join
     (select Type, sum(Units) as sumunits
      from mytable
      group by Type
     ) t
     on tb.type = t.type
order by t.sumunits desc, tb.sumunits desc;
```